# sealed class implementation query

Tags: c++, class, virtual, sealed

I was reading the C++ faqs on http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html , when i came accross this code to implement a 'sealed' class:

```
class Base{
    public:
      friend class A;
    private:
      Base(){cout<<"Base constructor called";}
};

class A : public virtual Base{
   public:
     A(){cout<<"A const called";}
};

class B : private A{};

int main(){
  A a;
  //B b;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

I did not understand how by using the virtual keyword, 'sealed' class effect is achieved. If i remove the virtual keyword, then it has no 'sealed' effect. Why?

Answer (score 1):

It works because due to the way virtual inheritance works, B must construct Base- which it can't, because Base's constructor is private. Only A can construct Base. In normal inheritance, B constructs A, which constructs Base, which is fine because A can construct Base and B can construct A.

Comment: What are we telling actually by saying  - public virtual Base?

Comment: @Abhi: That the Base is inherited virtually- that is, for any class derived from A and any other class that virtually inherits from Base, there is just one copy of Base, not multiple, and that instance of Base is constructed by the most derived class. It's a very complex topic.

Comment: What if I use a private inheritance? Will private inheritance be ok here? Actually, I've tested that the `private virtual` inheritance works fine. And so I think that use private inheritance will be more reasonable here. After all you don't want some one to use a `Base*` to manipulate `A` object, the Base class is not designed for OOP. It's just a utility. Plz comments.